# Semi donot chart with highcharts

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have been trying to achieve a chart like below using Highcharts library.

[image: Semi Circled Donot chart]

All i have been able to achieve is this http://jsfiddle.net/HpdwR/1489/ . So is there a way i could control how much the outer circle covers and its color. Also putting a title at the center of the chart.

Here is the config i have used to draw the chart

```
{
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market share, April, 2011'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total percent market share'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            shadow: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>' + this.point.name + '</b>: ' + this.y + ' %';
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Browsers',
        data: [
            ["Chrome", 70]
        ],
        size: '60%',
        innerSize: '60%',
        showInLegend: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }]
}
```

I would also like to know if there are any other js libraries that could draw the same.

Tooltip Image
[image: Tooltip change]

Comment: have you seen gauage chart ? http://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-solid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use solid-gauge type of chart with circle background (instead of default arc).

```
pane: {
        center: ['50%', '50%'],
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
            innerRadius: '0%',
            outerRadius: '80%',
            shape: 'circle'
        }
    },
plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    y: -25,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true,
                    format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:45px;color:#fff;">{y}</span><br/>' +
                        '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">%</span></div>'
                }
            }
        },
```

Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/12kwyftq/1/

Comment: Is there a possibility to add tooltip to the chart with images and all like i attached in original question ?

Comment: You can enable tooltip and customise [content](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter) and [position](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) by options. Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/12kwyftq/2/

Comment: I am trying to specify a color to the series through data (so that i can determine what color chart looks at server side itself) using this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/12kwyftq/3/ but color doesn't seem right . Whats wrong ? Also is there a general documentation on how JSON structure looks for each chart so that i can just send that data from server ajax method and leave just rendering of those points to High Charts

Comment: You need to define color in point not serie. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/12kwyftq/5/. All JSONs you can find in our demos [here](http://highcharts.com)

Answer (score 0):

you can use start angle ,end angle to make it desired view

```
           startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            center: ['50%', '75%']
```

example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/8u6hfkya/)

Comment: Do we have capability to set the background color and include images inside the tooltips ? If so any documentation links